# Excel columns to rows trasnpose

Tags: excel, excel-formula, transpose

I have this downloaded data in excel

[image]

I want to convert that data into this format so that i can calculate % diff across the months

[image: desired format]

Comment: a pivot table will do this easily.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @ScottCraner I agree.  This is specifically what pivot tables were made to do.

Comment: @ScottCraner I could not values in coumns from pivot table

Comment: I have used ServiceName as Rows but for UsageDate in the above table, I tried under PivotTable Columns section, Values section..it does not provide the desired result. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: serviceName goes in rows and usage date goes in columns with the cost being the return value.